# Namespace "src\AppBundle\Entity\YesNo" does not contain any mapped entities.

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2, and am trying to create objects using YML. The documentation for this seems very sketchy (compared to Symfony 1.x docs).

My tree structure looks like this:

```
├── src
│   ├── Acme
│   │   └── DemoBundle
│   ├── AppBundle
│   │   ├── AppBundle.php
│   │   ├── Controller
│   │   ├── Resources
│   │   ├── Tests
│   │   └── Utils
```

I have a file located in src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/reference_entities.yml which has the following contents:

```
## YAML Template.
---
# Yes/No
AppBundle\Entity\YesNo:
    type: entity
    table: yesno
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 100
    indexes:
        name_idx:
            columns: name

    uniqueConstraints:
        search_idx:
            columns: [name]
```

I type the following console command (as per the Symfony docs):

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities src/AppBundle/Entity/YesNo
```

And this is the output from the console:

```
Generating entities for namespace "src\AppBundle\Entity\YesNo"



  [RuntimeException]                                                            
  Namespace "src\AppBundle\Entity\YesNo" does not contain any mapped entities.  



doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you try with the YAML file but i think you should generate an entity class and implement all your getters and setters.

So put a class named `YesNo` in your entity folder:

```
<?php
namespace Test\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="yesno")
 */
class YesNo {
    .... all your getters / setters
}
```

The next one is that you should define a namespace before like `Acme` you have your bundle directly in your source folder. You should create something like

`Company\MyBundle`

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

Here are some examples how to create an entity class.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class

^^^^^
Here you can find complete examples and all commands you need.

Comment: I see, it looks like how to use the ORM has changed quite a lot in Symfony2. I last used Symfony 1.4.x with Propel. 

I'll make the changes your recommend, if they work, I'll accept your answer

Comment: Actually, I just had a look at the second link you sent. I prefer to use YML because I am familiar with it, and I can easily create the FKs , indices and ensure referential integrity etc.

Comment: You should really look at Symfony2 first ;) before your start... Entities are set in your Entity class... PLEASE READ THE MANUAL...

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: Ok. I read the manual. Is this a valid workflow: 1. Use generate-entity and choose yml format  2. Modify the generated yml file to add complex relationships etc  3. use generate-entities to update the generated php class?